# In Katalon Studio, how can i check JSON metadata

Tags: metadata, katalon-studio, web-api-testing

I am configuring Katalon Studio for WebAPI testing. I want to test the metadata (schema) check for the JSON received from API. How can I do that? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you receive the expected JSON by extending the code in the "Validation" tab of your REST method. The statement that allows you to do this is the following:

```
WS.verifyElementPropertyValue(response, contentOf, withPrecision)
```

So, if you expect a JSON like this: **{ "id":1, "name":"Joe" }**, you can use the following code:

```
WS.verifyElementPropertyValue(response, 'id', 1)
WS.verifyElementPropertyValue(response, 'name', 'Joe')
```

Katalon Studio offers another option too:

```
boolean successful = WS.validateJsonAgainstSchema(response,schema)
```

This way you can check a previously defined schema. Remember the schema must be String type. Katalon Studio autogenerate the following example:

```
String jsonPass =
"""
{
  "\$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "\$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's last name."
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  }
}
"""
boolean successful = WS.validateJsonAgainstSchema(response,jsonPass)
```

If you need more information about this (or a better explanation), check here Katalon documentation:

1. [ws-send-request-and-verify](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/legacy/katalon-studio-enterprise/keywords/web-service-keywords/ws-send-request-and-verify)
2. [ws-validate-json-string-against-a-schema](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/legacy/katalon-studio-enterprise/keywords/web-service-keywords/ws-validate-json-string-against-a-schema)

Hope it helps you!